# Javascript Transformation Missing Objects

Tags: javascript

Hi I am transforming objects

I have write the following program to add newName in the array

If you take a look resultedEvents, categoryName and name is missing in the result.

```js
const result2 = {
    "resultedEvents": [
        {
            "categoryName": "Football",
            "name": "Arsenal vs Aston Villa",
            "resultedMarkets": [
                {
                    "name": "Asian Handicap",
                },
                
      ]
    },
        {
            "categoryName": "Football",
            "name": "Arsenal vs Aston Villa (Live)",
            "resultedMarkets": [
                {
                    "name": "Asian Handicap -0.5 (1-3)",
        }
      ]
    }
    ]
}

const data2= result2.resultedEvents.map(items => {
    const newResult = items.resultedMarkets.map(function (item) {
      const newName = item.name.replace(/( -?\d+([.,]\d+)?)/g, "");
      return {...item,  newName};
    })
    return {  resultedMarkets: newResult  }
  }
);

console.log(data2)
```

Above program is giving me following

`Output`

```
[
    {
        "resultedMarkets": [
            {
                "name": "Asian Handicap",
                "newName": "Asian Handicap"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "resultedMarkets": [
            {
                "name": "Asian Handicap -0.5 (1-3)",
                "newName": "Asian Handicap (1-3)"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

`Expected`

```
{
    "resultedEvents": [{
            "categoryName": "Football",
            "name": "Arsenal vs Aston Villa",
            "resultedMarkets": [{
                    "name": "Asian Handicap",
                    "newName": "Asian Handicap"
                }

            ]
        },
        {
            "categoryName": "Football",
            "name": "Arsenal vs Aston Villa (Live)",
            "resultedMarkets": [{
                "name": "Asian Handicap -0.5 (1-3)",
                "newName": "Asian Handicap (1-3)"
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue I just want to add newName in the result, rest should be as it is

Comment: Please be aware that you're using regular JS objects, not JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are returning only `resultedMarkets` in your outer `map`

just add `...items` like this

```js
const result2 = {
    "resultedEvents": [
        {
            "categoryName": "Football",
            "name": "Arsenal vs Aston Villa",
            "resultedMarkets": [
                {
                    "name": "Asian Handicap",
                },
                
      ]
    },
        {
            "categoryName": "Football",
            "name": "Arsenal vs Aston Villa (Live)",
            "resultedMarkets": [
                {
                    "name": "Asian Handicap -0.5 (1-3)",
        }
      ]
    }
    ]
}

const data2= result2.resultedEvents.map(items => {
    const newResult = items.resultedMarkets.map( item => {
      const newName = item.name.replace(/( -?\d+([.,]\d+)?)/g, "");
      return {...item,  newName};
    })
    return {...items,  resultedMarkets: newResult  }
  }
);

console.log(data2)
```